# Conjugate or VB update for normal likelihood with shifted variance

Tags: bayesian, references, variational-bayes, conjugate-prior

Consider following model with normal likelihood at time $t$.

\begin{align*}
y_t | \mu_t, \sigma_t^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2 + P_t)
\end{align*}

we would like to find some priors $\mathcal{F}(\mu)$ and $\mathcal{G}(\sigma^2)$ (or joint) which are either conjugate or allow mean field variational bayes approach for a given general sequence $[P_t]_{t=1,\ldots, T}$ with $P_t \geq 0 \forall t$.

For example, if $P_t$ is a sequence of zeros, taking $\mathcal{F}(\mu)$ to be normal and $\mathcal{G}(\sigma^2)$ inverse gamma allows to use a mean-field variational Bayes approach: the approximation to posterior distributions $\mu \vert y$ and $\sigma^2 \vert y$ belong to the same family of distributions as the priors.

Having tried approaches similar to above, I keep hitting issues, with no success. I would appreciate any hints or references.